# How to show a temporary image(placeholder) till actual image loads from server , Angular2

Tags: angular

I am currently learning angular2. I have situation where I need to load image from web server, which takes some time, till than the img tag is not rendered / size remains 0 px. which looks odd in layout when image loaded properly.

Is it possible to show a temporary image till actual image loads.

EDIT :: my img tag is now like this ::

```
<img [src]="getImageUrl(package.id,package.poster_path) || 'assets/img/no_image.png'" alt="" class="bookposterImg" />
```

But its not working. no_image is not shown till server image arrives.

Comment: Do you actually want a placeholder image, or just an element the size of the image to be loaded, to hold its place in the layout? In the latter case, do you already know how large the image will be prior to loading it? This isn't really an Angular problem, you can do it by putting the `img` in another element with an explicit size.

Answer (score 0):

Use If condition like this

```
<img class="logo" [src]="Server_image || Placeholder_imagw" alt="Anything">
```

Comment: Just out of curosity -- how angular2 decides that whether I need Server_image OR Placeholder_imagw, if both are available.

Comment: its depends on priority, firstly angular will check for `server_image`  than for `placeholder` one

Comment: So it is like that , it is the first parameter in "src" takes higher priority

Comment: may be because you not binding URL directly instead via function call, could you recreate same problem on some plunker ?

Comment: Do not work, it is still displaying the alt attribute during the image loading